# core data fill an NSArray with date attributes

Tags: date, core-data, nsarray

I have a core data DB:
Entity: UserDates with the following attributes enteredDate (Type Date) and userStatus (Type Bool)

My TableViewController is all set up and everything works.

My question is, how do I fill an NSArray with only the enteredDates attributes?
So that my array looks like this:

```
array_name [0] contains enteredDate1
array_name [1] contains enteredDate2
array_name [2] contains enteredDate3
...
```

At this point I don't care about the userStatus attributes. I just need to know how to fill the array with all the enteredDate attributes, so I can use it for calculations like:

difference in dates = array_name [1] - array_name [0]    // of course I would use the appropriate distance of dates method...

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question right, I think you want to execute your fetch request that will return the array of UserDates, then call NSArray's `-valueForKey:` on the array to get an array of enteredDates:

```
NSArray *results = [myManagedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:myRequest error:nil];
NSArray *enteredDates = [results valueForKey:@"enteredDate"];
```

Comment: Thanks you very much @Jon Brooks,
Your answer saved me a lot of headache.
I absolutely appreciate you taking the time and answering, truly generous of you.
With that information I was able to complete my code-goal for today :-)

Thanks again buddy!